# Yup validation schema in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, yup

How can I change Yup validation schema on form submit.
I have yup schema where I am comparing date time.
I set the date time value in yup.
It should not be exceeded to the max

```js
schema: object({
    at: date()
      .max(new Date()),
  }),
```

The problem is maximum date is set at the time of first rendering.

Comment: you can use test method as follow
`let schema = number().test(
  'is-42',
  "this isn't the number i want",
  (value) => value != 42,
);`

Comment: can you please elaborate it @InamUrRehman

Comment: Follow this code block in your component to test your logic. `test()`  method will return boolean based on your logic 
```const value = new Date();

const schema = object({
  heldOn: date().test({
    message: "Date & Time cannot be in the future",
    test: () => {
      // your logic
      return false;
    }
  })
});

schema.validate({
  heldOn: value
});
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-dew-9lj3o?file=/src/App.js
follow this code sandbox to see working example